# Mockito - How to restrict list type with list matchers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the following interface:

```
public interface ListHandler {

    public boolean add(List<?> list, Object element);

}
```

For which I want to ensure in a test that it only receives a list with of a certain type, e.g., `String`. I have coded the following test:

```
@Test
public void testAddOnlyString() {
    boolean actual = false;

    when(this.listHandlerMock.add(
        Matchers.anyListOf(String.class),
        Matchers.anyString()
    )).thenReturn(true);

    actual = this.listHandlerMock.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(), 1);
    assertTrue(actual);

    verify(this.listHandlerMock).add(
        Matchers.anyListOf(String.class),
        Matchers.anyString()
    );
}
```

But the test passes correctly.

Comment: Due to generic type erasure so you don't know the generic type at runtime. What I guess the `anyListOf` matcher does is checking that all elements of the list are of this type, but since the list is empty, it will never fail. Anyway, you know what list you are passing - why are you asserting on any list? Just extract to `list = new ArrayList<Integer>` and expect same object: `sameInstance(list)`

Comment: By the way, where is your actual object? All the test is doing is interacting with a mock. What are you testing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. Type for the list is cleaned at compile time(type erasure)
As an example this will print `true`:

```
System.out.println(new ArrayList<Integer>().equals(new ArrayList<String>()));
```

Also from the documentation of `Matchers.anyListOf`:

> This method don't do any type checks, it is only there to avoid
>   castingin your code.

If the list is not empty you can build a matcher that checks that every entry has the type you expect but for an empty list there is nothing you can do.

Comment: So, which is the aim of those matchers?

Comment: @Julen     Generic friendly alias to {@link Matchers#anyList()}.
     It's an alternative to SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to keep code clean of compiler warnings.

Comment: How is the warning generated? I'm trying to replicate it to understand the sense of the matchers.

Comment: @Julen this is another quetion; it is "generated" at compile time; just a compiler warning